# Is Hershbergers improved Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithim worth implementing?

Tags: algorithm

[Here is the article with code samples](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs350/spring06/Lecture-Handouts/hershberger92speeding.pdf)

Other than the C code he wrote are their any implementations? Is it worth making a python or R module out of the C code? Are their known flaws to the algorithm? Known improved implementations in C?